# Commit to alternative branch in git (leaving working copy unmodified)

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-commit

I'm working on a branch `topic`. I've made some changes which I want to commit on a side branch `attempt1`. After committing these changes, I want to continue working on `topic`, **from my current state** (as opposed to going back to the last commit on `topic`).

The reason to do this is, I need to work some more before the changes are good enough to get into a published branch (I push `topic` regularly), but I want to save a copy of the current state in case I mess up the rework. I don't want to change my working copy while I'm doing this. I expect to end up with an empty index.

Note that I want to keep `attempt1` around for a while — this isn't just a very temporary commit that I'll rebase away a few minutes later. Sometimes I decide to change my approach on `topic`, and in parallel pursue an alternative approach on `attempt1`. I want to create a branch, not just stash one commit.

Also, I'm after something robust, so interactive rebasing is out. Temporarily committing to `topic` then moving the commit to a new branch would be fine, as long as I can do that without modifying the working copy.

In graphical terms, I'm in the state

```
HEAD
 |
 v
 A  topic
```

with uncommitted changes, and I want to get to

```
HEAD
 |
 v
 A  topic
  \
   B  attempt1
```

with an unchanged working copy that's identical to B.

I could do `git checkout -b attempt1` then (`git add` new files and `git rm` deleted files then) `git commit -a`. But then how would I switch back to `topic` without modifying the working tree?

Basically, how do I do

```
git commit --to-alternate-branch=attempt1
```

or (after creating and committing to `attempt1`)

```
git checkout --do-not-modify-working-tree topic
```

or `git stash --no-revert` (followed by `git branch attempt1 stash@{0}`), or whatever? All the combinations I can think of mess up my working copy at some point.

Comment: If the attempt1 is local branch and not pushed, it won't mess up topic branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that any new files have been added with `git add` and any removed files have been declared with `git rm`. Then:

```
git commit -a
git branch attempt1
git reset HEAD^
```

This creates a commit on the current branch, then undoes that commit (a mixed reset changes where the current branch points to, but does not modify the working copy). In between, create a new branch whose tip is that commit, without switching to that branch.

The index ends up empty. If you want to have the changes in the index, use a soft reset (`git reset --soft HEAD^`).

Answer (score 0):

## Using git

Create your new branch `attempt1` in the way you described in your question (that is, just as usual). Then:

```
git checkout topic
git checkout attempt1 .
```

`git help checkout` shows what this variant does exactly. This will make it so your new index is like `attempt1`, but you can easily unstage if you wish.

Note that if your original state contains both staged and unstaged  changes, this distinction will be lost.

## Without using git

Assuming your working directory is called `src`...

```
cd ..
cp -r src src2  
cd src2
git branch attempt1
git add ... 
git commit
git push origin attempt1
cd ..
rm -rf src2
```

Kind of sledgehammer'ish, but it does what you asked.

If you do not have a `origin` or do not wish to push there,  then instead of the push:

```
cd ../src
git remote add tmp PATHTOSRC2
git fetch tmp
git branch attempt1 tmp/attempt1
git remote del tmp
rm -rf ../src2
```

Comment: This modifies my working copy, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Gilles: It is the closest you can get with git tools. Note that the second checkout is not a normal checkout, the "." is important.  It only modifies your working copy insofar as afterwards everything is staged, which you can easily undo.  Aside from that, the next simplest method would be to copy your working directory (using `cp` or whatever OS tools), create `attempt1` there and then pull that into your original wd.

Comment: I have added in the second way for you, but unless you tell us exactly why not modifying the wd is so important, it is hard to guess at the correct answer.

Comment: One reason is to prevent data loss: I've sometimes forgotten to add or remove files, and ended up with missing or extra files after the manipulations. So “no modifying the working tree” is a safety measure. Another reason is to preserve an up-to-date build (that's for performance, so that saving my partial work is fast so I can do it often without it being a hurdle).

Comment: @gilles, I see. I'd suggest simple file system backups then (just copy the repos somewhere)  for security. To get fast when doing partial commits, getting used to juggling the index and partial-file commits (with `git gui`, `git add -i` or a good editor of your choice which has a proper `git` mode has paid off well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description of "why", I can tell you there's a simpler way.  If you decide you just really want to use a temporary branch, then of course you could.

Now, the method suggested by AnoE will often work, but may not reflect deletes correctly.  There are multiple ways to adjust the procedure for that, but I hate trying to keep track of them; so instead you could use stashes.

```
git stash
git checkout -b attempt1
git stash apply
git commit
git checkout topic
git stash pop
```

But like I said, this is all really reinventing the wheel.  You don't need a branch to store a state you can come back to.  You just need a commit

```
git commit
```

And you would argue that you never want to push the commit; this is no problem.  If you finish your work and it's good,

```
git rebase -i
```

You'll see a list of commits, each marked `pick`; this is a TODO list for `git rebase`.  Find the commits you don't want, and change the *next* commit's command to `squash`.  So for example, the TODO list comes up as

```
pick 00000001 first attempt
pick 00000002 here's a commit I want to push
```

you change it to

```
pick 00000001 first attempt - don't push this
squash 00000002 but here's a commit I want to push
```

and the "temporary" commit will be wiped from your branch history.  Yes, it's a history rewrite, but you're doing it *before sharing the branch* (that's the whole point) so it's fine.

Comment: Stashing modifies the working directory, so it's out. Rebasing doesn't let me keep the alternative branch, which is something I often want: save work, polish a part of it and publish that, then continue polishing the rest with the save still available.

Comment: @Gilles - First of all, rebase does *not* prevent you keeping the alternative branch.  As long as there's a ref (tag or branch) on the old commit line, it persists.  (Even if there's not such a ref, actually; but then it's harder to reach and could eventually be gc'd.)  I didn't address that because you didn't state it as a requirement.

Comment: @Gilles - Secondly, the procedure of "stash , do stuff , apply the stash" does *not* change the working directory.  In fact the whole point of the stash command is that it preserves the working directory (and index).  If what you meant to say is that you can't even tolerate temporary changes to the working directory, then you'll have to either use plumbing commands or bypass git's interfaces altogether and directly manipulate the repo metadata; both of which are bad ideas IMO

Comment: @Gilles - I see from your comments on the alternate answer, that you want git to correct for your errors if you don't add a file.  Again, git stash is the answer to this, because you can tell it preserve the untracked files as well (`-u`)